# Best way to remove items from a list based on DateTime

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have a System.Collections.Generic.List of time-stamped strings which look like this:

- 14-Oct-2013_10.36-34: JobID=1234, Status=FAILED.
- 14-Nov-2013_11.12-36: JobID=2345, Status=SUCCESS.
- 10-Dec-2013_14.20-42: JobID=3456, Status=SUCCESS.

etc.

(The list is guaranteed to be in chronological order, and despite the odd separators it reads as you might expect, e.g. Day-Month-Year_24hr.Minutes-Seconds )

And I have two DateTime objects: startDateTime, endDateTime

I want to process the list so that all that remains after processing are those entries whose time stamps fall within the range defined by my two DateTime objects.

Given that, I think I have two questions:

1. How can I convert "10-Dec-2013_14.20-42" into a DateTime
2. How can I delete items from a list as I'm running through it?

I think I can manage the rest of the process.

All help gratefully accepted.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you generating this list of strings yourself? Why not define a class?

Comment: The strings were generated by a long-departed Perl coder and dumped to file. At present I plan to read them into my program, trim to user-provided DateTimes, then produce a report on what's left.

Comment: DateTime.Parse is looking good.  I can pass in this:  string dateTimeFormat = "dd-MMM-yy_HH.mm-ss"; and all will be well, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes the date portion of your string and converts it to a valid `DateTime` using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) *(using 24-hour format, since there's no am or pm in the string)*.

The result is a new list, with only the string in it that fall between your date range.

```
var filteredList
    = (from o in originalList
       let dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
                  o.Substring(0, o.IndexOf(":")),
                  "dd-MMM-yyyy_HH.mm-ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
       where dt >= startDateTime
          && dt <= endDateTime
       select o).ToList();
```

To remove items from the original list:

```
originalList.RemoveAll(
    x => (from o in originalList
          let dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
                     o.Substring(0, o.IndexOf(":")),
                     "dd-MMM-yyyy_HH.mm-ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
          where dt >= startDateTime
             && dt <= endDateTime
          select o).Contains(x));
```

Note that `ParseExact` will throw an exception if the input on any of your lines cannot be converted to a valid date.

Comment: Thanks. This approach looks good, but what is the variable "s"?  Should it be "o"?

Answer (score 1):

To parse dates, use the [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

If you have a generic list, it has a method [`List<T>.RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) that suits your needs.